$E[(X+Y)^{a}] > E[(X)^{a}]$?
Assume I have two strictly positive i.i.d. random variables, $X$ and $Y$. Under what conditions is the following inequality true?
$$E[(X+Y)^{a}] > E[(X)^{a}], \hspace{2mm} a \in (0,1)$$
Should have an easy proof, however, I am struggling a lot, because my first hunch was using Jensen's inequality which clearly does not work.
As follow up questions,
a) Can this be proved if they are positively correlated?
b) Is it somewhat easier to prove if these random variables are iid with binary distributions, such that, with probability $p$ these are equal to $0<c<1$ and with probability $1-p$ equal to 1?

Since $X+Y > X$ for all values of $Y$, and $w = z^a$ for $a > 0$ is a monotonic transform of $z$...

Is this true regardless of the correlation structure?

Since $Y > 0$, it must be that for any specified $X$, $X+Y > X$., regardless of which $Y$ is observed. Correlations etc. are irrelevant to this fact.

Part of this can be done before we get to any stochastic aspects of the problem at all.  For all $x>0$, $y>0$ and $a>0$ you have $x+y>x$ so that:
$$(x+y)^a>x^a.$$
Consequently, for any joint distribution of $(X,Y)$ where the support is on the strictly positive values for both variables, for any $a>0$ you have:
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}((X+Y)^a)
&= \mathbb{E}(X^a) + \mathbb{E}((X+Y)^a-X^a) \\[18pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(X^a) + \int \limits_\mathbb{{R}^2} ((x+y)^a-x^a) \ dP(x,y) \\[6pt]
&= \mathbb{E}(X^a) + \int \limits_\mathbb{{R}_+^2} \underbrace{((x+y)^a-x^a)}_{+} \ dP(x,y) \\[6pt]
&> \mathbb{E}(X^a). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$
(The last step follows from the fact that the integrand is strictly positive over the support and the integral is over a space with positive probability measure; see this related question.)
